# Show all axioms Coq

Tags: coq

I want to see all axioms which were used by my proof.
What are the easiest ways to obtain such information?
Which commands or scripts or tools I shall use?
I am interested in either all axioms or all used axioms.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use the

```
Print Assumptions foobar.
```

vernacular command, described [here](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/Reference-Manual008.html#hevea_command99)